# How to remove facebook embed video header bar in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, mobile

Seems in these few days, Facebook added a header bar inside the embed video iframe, overlay on top of the video.

It only show in mobile browser (both Android Chrome & iOS Safari)

Here's the [example page](https://www.lifetv.hk/news/%E6%B8%AF%E7%91%9E%E9%9F%93%E5%A4%A7%E5%AD%B8%E5%88%86%E4%BA%AB%E9%86%AB%E5%AD%B8%E6%88%90%E6%9E%9C-%E8%81%AF%E6%89%8B%E7%A0%94%E5%89%B5%E6%96%B0%E6%8A%80%E8%A1%93%E9%86%AB%E5%BF%83%E8%85%B8/)

[image: facebook header bar in mobile browser]

We are using these code to embed video into the page

```
<div class='fb-video'
data-href='https://www.facebook.com/lifetvnews/videos/xxxxxxx/'
data-width='1280'
data-allowfullscreen='true'
data-autoplay='true'>
</div>
```

Anyone has idea how to remove that header bar from mobile browser? thanks!!!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/157171235015171/

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved, it was due to the issue on Facebook side

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/353698218434489/